# How to create another world in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With the arrival of 1.8, I'm wondering how I can create another world on SMP and set a warp to travel on both.

I think that way, I'll be able the generated a new world with 1.8 update and move my schematic from world 1.7 to the world made in 1.8

So how can we create another world on SMP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock Minecraft servers can't do this, but [Bukkit](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Main_Page) has support for running an arbitrary number of worlds. If you aren't already running Bukkit, you'll need to install it and set it up to use your existing world. (Be sure to make keep a clean backup of your world files somewhere safe in case of catastrophe!)

Once you have Bukkit running, the [MultiVerse](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/multiverse-core/) plugin (which also requires the transitional [PermissionsBukkit](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-dev-permissionsbukkit-v1-2k-official-default-groups-plugin-1000.26785/) plugin until Bukkit's own Permissions API is complete) will give you access to Bukkit's multi-worlds capabilities with commands and configuration files.

Once you have multi-worlds tested out and working properly, you will have to:

- Wait for Minecraft to update to 1.8. (I know, the suspense is killing me too!)
- Wait for Bukkit to update to a 1.8-compatible build. Because of the obfuscation in Mojang's code, the Bukkit team always needs a number of days to unravel the new server code, add Bukkit's changes, test, and release an update.
- Create a new 1.8 world. Probably the easiest way is to log in as an admin or op on the newly-updated Bukkit server and issue a simple MultiVerse `/mvcreate MYNEWWORLDNAME NORMAL` command. Alternatives (such as the `mvimport` command) exist and are covered in the MultiVerse documentation.

MultiVerse will then give you the tools for making warp portals, setting permissions on who can go and do what where, and all that fun stuff.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie — There's been some rumor that 1.8 won't be obfuscated (as part of the promised developer program). I'm keeping my fingers crossed for faster update schedules!

Comment: @Ben I know Notch is planning on moving to unobfuscated code at some point. It would be great if 1.8 was it! … but I won't be surprised if they wait for a less monumental update.

Comment: Don't use Permissions, it's outdated. Use [PermissionsBukkit](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-dev-permissionsbukkit-v1-2k-official-default-groups-plugin-1000.26785/) instead.

Comment: @Jake MultiVerse docs currently say Permissions is required; since I haven't installed it myself I can't confirm whether that's changed or whether the new PermissionsBukkit drops in as a replacement. Someone should test this and report back! ;)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Well, the problem is, you're linking the wiki, which is often outdated. Link the plugins themselves. So, use [MultiVerse](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/edit-misc-tp-fun-multiverse-2-0-world-management-1060.3707/) and [PermissionsBukkit](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-dev-permissionsbukkit-v1-2k-official-default-groups-plugin-1000.26785/).

Comment: Updated! I also noted that PermissionsBukkit is only necessary until Bukkit's own permissions API is complete. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Multiverse requires a SuperPerms capable plugin. Meaning one that adheres to the Bukkit Perms api. I've updated [our wiki](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki/Permissions#wiki-superperms) to state this.